# How do I pass a data class into the parameters of a regular class in python?

Tags: python

I want to instantiate a regular class Motion using the dataclass Points, and the regular class is supposed to have four parameters namely self, x, y, and z. However, when I pass the dataclass to the regular class,and run the test method, I get the error:

> Motion.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'.

How do I fix this?

Source code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass 
class Points:
    x: int
    y: int
    z: int




class Motion:
   def __init__(self, x:int, y:int, z:int):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.z = z

   def test(self):
      print(self.x, self.y, self.z)

result = Motion(Points(1,2,3))
result.test()
```

Comment: Maybe you want `Motion` to have `def __init__(self, points: Points)`. It's worth noting `Points` is really *a* "Point".

Comment: That's because it is looking for 3 integers, not for a class object. You'd need to change the method signature to accept a class and then extract x,y,z from it within the method body or pass the values directly to the method (e.g., `Motion(Points.x, Points.y, Points.z)`

Comment: `Motion(**dataclasses.asdict(Points(1, 2, 3)))` - this has to be a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`dataclasses.asdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict):

```py
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass


@dataclass
class Points:
    x: int
    y: int
    z: int


class Motion:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, z: int):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def test(self):
        print(self.x, self.y, self.z)


result = Motion(**asdict(Points(1, 2, 3)))
result.test()
```

Prints:

```
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You're only passing one `Point` to the class, so you shouldn't have 3 parameters. The dataclass is not spread into separate arguments.

```
class Motion:
   def __init__(self, p: Point):
       self.x = p.x
       self.y = p.y
       self.z = p.z

   def test(self):
      print(self.x, self.y, self.z)
```

Alternatively, don't replicate the functionality of the `Point` dataclass. Instead of extracting each coordinate, just save the `Point` object.

```
class Motion:
   def __init__(self, p: Point):
       self.point = p

   def test(self):
      print(self.point.x, self.point.y, self.point.z)
```

And if you want more terse syntax, you could define properties:

```
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.point.x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, new_x):
        self.point.x = new_x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `asdict` as illustrated in another answer, but with a little more work you can pass it exactly like `kwargs`. There are only 2 requirements for a class to support dictionary unpacking. It must implement `__getitem__` and `keys`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from typing import Any, Iterable

@dataclass
class BaseDataclass:
    # required for dictionary unpacking
    def keys(self) -> Iterable:
        return asdict(self).keys()
        
    # required for dictionary unpacking
    def __getitem__(self, key:str) -> Any:
        return getattr(self, key, None)
      
        
@dataclass
class Point(BaseDataclass):
    x:int 
    y:int
    z:int
    

class Motion:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, z: int):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def test(self):
        # you don't have to specify each property individually
        print(vars(self))
        

m = Motion(**Point(1, 2, 3))
m.test() # {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}
```

One thing you may want to consider, though: `Motion` is a `Point`

```
from __future__  import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from typing      import Any, Iterable
import json


@dataclass
class BaseDataclass:
    # required for dictionary unpacking
    def keys(self) -> Iterable:
        return asdict(self).keys()
    
    # required for this example    
    def values(self) -> Iterable:
        return asdict(self).values()
    
    # we have keys and values, might as well include items     
    def items(self) -> Iterable:
        return asdict(self).items()
    
    # required for dictionary unpacking    
    def __getitem__(self, key:str) -> Any:
        return getattr(self, key, None)
    
    # nice
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return json.dumps(asdict(self), indent=4)
    
    # nice
    def __call__(self, **kwargs) -> BaseDataclass:
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if hasattr(self, key):
                setattr(self, key, value)
                
        return self


@dataclass
class Point(BaseDataclass):
    x:int 
    y:int
    z:int


@dataclass
class Motion(Point):
    speed_x:int
    speed_y:int
    speed_z:int
    
    
def stats(msg:str):
    print(msg)
    print('point:' , p, sep='\n')
    print('motion:', m, sep='\n', end='\n\n')
    

p = Point(1,2,3)
m = Motion(*p.values(), 5, 10, 15)
stats('#new point and motion')


p(x=3,y=4,z=5)
m(**p)
stats('#change point then apply to motion')


m(**p(y=5000), speed_x=30)
stats('#change point while applying to motion')

# extra: override a property without changing the original
m(**{**p, 'x':1, 'y':1}) # more than one value on one line
m(**p).x = 1             # only one value
m.y = 1                  # override proceeding values like this
```

###### output

```py
#new point and motion
point:
{
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2,
    "z": 3
}
motion:
{
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2,
    "z": 3,
    "speed_x": 5,
    "speed_y": 10,
    "speed_z": 15
}

#change point then apply to motion
point:
{
    "x": 3,
    "y": 4,
    "z": 5
}
motion:
{
    "x": 3,
    "y": 4,
    "z": 5,
    "speed_x": 5,
    "speed_y": 10,
    "speed_z": 15
}

#change point while applying to motion
point:
{
    "x": 3,
    "y": 5000,
    "z": 5
}
motion:
{
    "x": 3,
    "y": 5000,
    "z": 5,
    "speed_x": 30,
    "speed_y": 10,
    "speed_z": 15
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Motion(Points(1,2,3))`, you'r passing `Points(1,2,3)` as the `x` parameter of the constructor.

It appears you want to pass the attributes x, y, and z of the point (`Points` plural seems to be a misnomer) to the constructor instead.

If the dataclass was a dictionary, you could do this:

```
p = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
Motion(**p)  # unpack the dictionary
```

You could define how your class is a mapping, but for a simple dataclass, this trick works:

```
result = Motion(**Points(1,2,3).__dict__)
```

It takes the attributes and values of the `Points` as a dictionary, and then unpacks it the same way as in the previous example.

Comment: I think it's preferable to use the `asdict()` method rather than accessing the `__dict__` attribute directly, as shown in Andrej's answer.

Comment: I agree - I considered removing my answer, but I felt it adds something. The `.asdict()` solution is definitely preferable. (Having said that, I agree with the underlying idea of your answer even more - which is that some more thought may need to go into what OP actually wants to pass here, instead of getting code to work)